# Rendering carousels in reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I have a json schema, on depending this schema I want to show the slider/carousel, So if the json schema has 3 Objects, I want to render Slider 3 times in ReactJS Component and images in that Object's Array as well in the slider / carousel.

Let's say I have 3 Objects in my json then this Carousel should be rendered 3 times

```
import APIData from "../../data/api.json";
            <Carousel {...settings}>
              {APIData.map((data, index) => {
                data.images.map((images, index) => {
                  return <img key={index} src={images} alt={index} />;
                });
              })}
            </Carousel>
```

How many times will I have to map that and how can I do that?

`api.json`

```
[
  {
    "id": "DR001",
    "propertyFullName": "8838, Brook St, NY",
    "propertyShortName": "Anchorage, AK 99501",
    "features": ["2 beds", "1 bath", "865 sqft"],
    "description": "data.",
    "images": [
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"
    ],
    "status": true
  },
  {
    "id": "DR002",
    "propertyFullName": "8838, Brook St, NY",
    "propertyShortName": "Anchorage, AK 99501",
    "features": ["2 beds", "1 bath", "865 sqft"],
    "description": "data.",
    "images": [
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide3",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide4",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide5",
      "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide6"
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Please provide the `json`'s example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our `APIData` is array of objects, the object structure is this.

```
{
  "id": "DR001",
  ... fields,
  "images": [
    "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide1",
    "http://placehold.it/1000x400/ffffff/c0392b/&text=slide2"
  ],
}
```

We need to wrap every object with the `Carousel` Component so first we loop over the `APIData` array with [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) which gives us an `object` with each iteration, we then loop over the `images` array inside of that object and render an `img` tag with the source of the image for every image in the array.

```
// If all what we are doing is returning something from an arrow function
// we can omit the return statement and the {} and just wrap it in () or not wrap it
// at all but with () it is more readable
APIData.map(data => (
  <Carousel key={data.id} {...settings}>
    {data.images.map(imgSrc => (
      <img key={imgSrc} src={imgSrc} alt={data.propertyFullName} />
    ))}
  </Carousel>
));
```

To see what the `map` is doing you can execute this code.

```
APIData.map((data, index) => {
  console.log(`Outer map iteration number ${index + 1}`);
  console.log('Outer map data', data);
  console.log('Inner map within the outer map');
  data.images.map(img => {
    console.log(img);
  });
});
```

Comment: this looks clean

Comment: Hey Asaf, can you add some explanation to it?

Comment: I've added an explanation, Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, it is, indeed helpful, improved the entire code after this

Answer (score 0):

Loop trough each **APIData** item and return **carousel** with **images**

```
     {
      APIData.map((data, index) => {
        return (
           <Carousel {...settings}>
             {data.images.map((images, index) => {
                return <img key={index} src={images} alt={index} />;
             });}
           </Carousel>
        )
      })
     }
```

Comment: Even if I return it, it will render only 1 Carousel

Comment: is it rendering two image one for each object in array?

Comment: YES! Exactly...In a different version of code, it will render 2 carousels vertically with all 6 slides

Comment: Don't you think it is necessary to iterate the `<Carousel>` too ?

Comment: You want same number of carousel as entries in array `APIData` or  carousel or in one carousel all images should be there?

Comment: I want carousel for each object that is present in json schema

Comment: I can confirm that on Monday :)

Comment: This has some syntactical error, apart of that your's and Asaf's answers are identical

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";
import APIData from "../../data/api.json";
import Carousel from '....';

export default class SimpleSlider extends React.Component {

    sliders(){
       return APIData.map(({id,images}) => {
        return (
           <Carousel {...settings} key={id}>
             {images.map(({image}) => {
                return <img key={image} src={image} alt={image}/>;
             });}
           </Carousel>
        )
      })
    }

    render() {
      return (
       {this.sliders()}
      );
   }
}
```

Comment: I have been edited my answer please check if ur helpful